# Typescript Generics: Map<string, Interface> Get Objects with the Name of the Interface?

Tags: typescript

is it possible with typescript generics to get a former initilized class that implements interface y get retrieved by a generic function?

```
interface InterfaceX{};
interface InterfaceY extends InterfaceX {
  doSomethingOnObjtY(): void;
};
class ClassY implements InterfaceY{  doSomethingOnObjtY(): void {};};
class ClassZ {

  map: Map<string, InterfaceX> = new Map();
  constructor(){
    const ObjtY = new ClassY();

    this.map.set(typeof ObjtY, ObjtY);
  }
  getObject<T extends InterfaceX>():InterfaceX{
    return this.map.get(T as string); //<-- this is not possible, any ideas?
  }
}

const objZ = new ClassZ();
(<InterfaceY>objZ.getObject<InterfaceY>()).doSomethingOnObjtY();
```

Well in my case i need to convert the Type to a string to query the map and get the corresponding Object of that type. Could this be achieved in other ways or what i need to do to get things working?

https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-2wmoha

Thanks in advance

Edit://
replaced with executable typescript code

Comment: Your should post an example that compiles.

Comment: ... Well that is why i need help with typescript generics. i know this example is not compileable...

Comment: Interfaces do not exists at runtime.

Comment: I know that rly. Well maybe i can not explain my problem good enough

Comment: i want to query a map with the interface name to get a former initialized obj out of the map. Is it possible?

Comment: No, because the types do not exist at runtime. Querying the map happens at runtime.

Comment: Any other solution that i could get something like getObject<InterfaceY>():ObjectY?

Comment: It is somehow an advanced factory pattern